# How to set addtarget to custom UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a custom UIView called Icons. Everything is working perfectly fine right now except one thing. The problem that i am having is being able to set userinteraction to be working or to either make the button i have in my class to be working. When I add a target to the button, i get an error that crashes everything and with the userinteraction to the view, i get no response.

```
class Icons: UIView {
    let xUnit = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/20
    let yUnit = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height/30
    var name: String = String()
    var image: UIImage = UIImage()
    let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 16.0)!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.userInteractionEnabled = true



    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func addCustomView(name:String, image: UIImage ){
        let label: UILabel = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 1.5*xUnit, 3.4*xUnit, 2.7*xUnit)
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.font = font
        label.text = name
        self.addSubview(label)

        let btn: UIButton = UIButton()
        btn.frame=CGRectMake(0.3*xUnit, 0, 2.5*xUnit, 2.5*xUnit)
        btn.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
        self.addSubview(btn)


    }
}
```

And this is the class I'm trying to get connect it with which is in a completely different class

```
func tapSettings(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    let touchPoint = tapGestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.view)
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(settings.frame, touchPoint)){
        print("hi")
    }
}
```

when I am trying to connect it to the button I say this:

`btn.addTarget(self,action: #selector(HomeScreen.tapSettings))`

and when I try and connect it to the view I say this :

```
let settingsTouch = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HomeScreen.tapSettings))
        settingsTouch.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        settingsTouch.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(settingsTouch)
```

Comment: Where is the code you are using to add a target to the button?

Comment: that i cant get the target connected to the function AdamPro13

Comment: oh with the tap gesture recognizer @ReinierMelian

Comment: the real problem is the name of the selector, try my answer

Comment: Edit your code, and a question, your `HomeScreen.tapSettings`is static method?

Comment: what do you mean static? @ReinierMelian and by the way, the function is in a completley different class

Comment: @AlexRabin my answer was edited

Comment: @AlexRabin did you finally resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    btn.addTarget(HomeScreen.self, action: #selector(HomeScreen.tapSettings(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code:

1. You are setting the target of the button to `self` when you should be setting it to an instance of HomeScreen, if that's where the method you want to call is declared
2. The argument a button action method receives is not `UITapGestureRecognizer`, but the clicked button instead, so you should replace your `tapSettings` method with something like this:

   `func tapSettings(button: UIButton){`